# determine and sort distance for several locations

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

I have about 15 locations in a mysql table with lat and long information.

Using PHP and google maps API Am able to calculate distance between 2 locations.

```
function GetDrivingDistance($lat1, $lat2, $long1, $long2) 
{ 
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=".$lat1.",".$long1."&destinations=".$lat2.",".$long2."&mode=driving&language=en-US"; 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch); 
$response_a = json_decode($response, true); 
$dist = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']; 
$time = $response_a['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['duration']['text']; 
return array('distance' => $dist, 'time' => $time); 
}
```

I want to to select one as fixed e.g. row 1 given lat and long

```
$query="SELECT lat, long from table WHERE location=1"
$locationStart = $conn->query($query); =
```

I want to calculate the distance to all other locations in the tables (other rows) and return the the outcome sorted by distance

tried to calculate each one alone and end up with very long code and takes too long to fetch that via api, also still not able to sort them this way!

any hint?

Comment: [`curl_multi_init`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) might a way to handle the requests, it *"Allows the processing of multiple cURL handles asynchronously."* so should be one way to speed up your cURL Requests. You could also just do [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) if you just wanted to cut down on all the `cURL` code.  As for the sorting, if you just pull out the numeric value for the distance, and had them all stored in an an array I imagine you could just use one of the inbuilt sorting functions like `natsort()`

Comment: hi Pigeon, i would like to test this any more details or code samples? i have no very good at php

Comment: I've added a comment with some rough working, that is the rough idea I was thinking of, any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** This is not a working solution, nor have I tested it, it is just a quick example I've done off the top of my head to provide a sort of code sample to go with my comment.

My brains still not fully warmed up, but I believe the bottom should at least act as a sort of guide to help put across the idea I was making in my comment, i'll try to answer any questions you have when I'm free. Hope it helps.

```
<?php 

define('MAXIMUM_REQUEST_STORE', 5); // Store 5 requests in each multi_curl_handle

function getCurlInstance($url) {
    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    return $handle;
}

$data = []; // Build up an array of Endpoints you want to hit. I'll let you do that.

// Initialise Variables
$totalRequests         = count($data);
$parallelCurlRequests  = [];
$handlerID             = 0;

// Set up our first handler
$parallelCurlRequests[$handlerID] = curl_multi_init();

// Loop through each of our curl handles
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalRequests; ++$i) {

    // We want to create a new handler/store every 5 requests. -- Goes off the constant MAXIMUM_REQUEST_STORE
    if ($i % MAXIMUM_REQUEST_STORE == 1 && $i > MAXIMUM_REQUEST_STORE) {
        ++$handlerID;
    }

    // Create a Curl Handle for the current endpoint
    // ... and store the it in an array for later use.
    $curl[$i] = getCurlInstance($data[$i]);

    // Add the Curl Handle to the Multi-Curl-Handle
    curl_multi_add_handle($parallelCurlRequests[$handlerID], $curl[$i]);
}

// Run each Curl-Multi-Handler in turn
foreach ($parallelCurlRequests as $request) {
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($request, $running);
    } while ($running);
}

$distanceArray = [];

// You can now pull out the data from the request.
foreach ($curl as $response) {
    $content = curl_multi_getcontent($response);
    if (!empty($content)) {
        // Build up some form of array.
        $response = json_decode($content);
        $location = $content->someObject[0]->someRow->location;
        $distance = $content->someObject[0]->someRow->distance;

        $distanceArray[$location] = $distance;
    }
}

natsort($distanceArray);
```